# Attack from Middle Man , how Resolve?

Tags: mysql, encryption, man-in-the-middle

I'm developing one site, my dates are encrypted in `AES-256-OFB` with functions of MySql, in this way I `encrypt` and `decrypt` in End To End, right?

If it is true, how resolve attack by `Middle Man`, in addition to using `SSL`? Are there any `encryptions` for this?

Explain me all. I know next to nothing about security. Help me. Thanks To all.

Comment: You're heading for a world of pain if you start encrypting the data you insert into the database rather than using an encrypted filesystem

Comment: TLS is mentioned below; use that.  If you are just curious by what mechanism MITM is foiled, an easy way is by proper use of a message authentication code or MAC.  See the problem with OFB alone is that a pseudorandom stream is XOR'd with plaintext.  If the MITM wants to change the last block and knows the plaintext, he can XOR the crypto with that plaintext and XOR again with his own plaintext.  Then it will decrypt without error to say whatever he wants it to say.  The MAC would reveal the alteration.  But just use TLS for practical applications.

Comment: @WDS For you what is the best mode for aes 256 (ecb,cbc,cfb1,cfb8,cfb128,ofb)?

Comment: @symcbean What do you meen?

Comment: No range queries, no partial matching, no sorting, limit on what you can do in procedures without injecting the encryption key (which rather defeats the purpose of encrypting)....

Answer (score 1):

TLS already protects against man-in-the-middle attacks (within the transport protocol). If you apply it correctly, you should be safe against them.